# Static IP Route without use isp

Tags: router

I have two routers, Router A & Router B is connected to my P2P link, 
P2P link is connected by rocket m-5 Router.
I wan't to set static routing in without ISP

Mikrotik Router A: 10.10.10.52/24 Lan port 3

Mikrotik Router A: 192.168.2.1/24 lan port 2

Mikrotik Router B: 10.10.10.51/24 lan port 3

Mikrotik Router B: 192.168.1.99/24 Lan Port 2

I have configure below Ip Route in MT Router.

Route: `IP route add dst-address=192.168.1.0/24 gateway=10.10.10.51`

Route: `IP route add dst-address=192.168.2.0/24 gateway=10.10.10.52`

Comment: So what is working and what isn't working with this setup? Right now you might just be missing a metric/weight for the route?

Comment: p2p is working in 192.168.1.0/24 ip sub net but not working different sub net   mask .

Comment: i wan't to ip sub net change to different ip range.

Comment: Sir
I Have 300 up Devices in My Network.
I have connected to different network with point to point (two rocket-m5 )router.
i wan't to static ip routing in my two ip address.
i don't use any isp for static routing.if! possible in two MT Router.

Comment: Maybe add some [kind of diagram](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) what you got going and which network is where and what kind of connection you'd like to setup. What would you like the new subnetmask to be and what happens when you set it up as you're saying it's not working?

Comment: Site 1:192.168.2.0/24 Network

Comment: Site1:192.168.2.0/24  connected to site 2:-192.168.1.0/24 network with ubiquiti Rocket-m5 devices p2p link. 192.168.2.0/24 ........ubiquiti link Mt Router ........switch.......ubiquiti link Mt router ....switch..192.168.1.0/24. site1 Mt Router :port 2 Ip:192.168.2.1/24 ,Port 3:-10.10.10.52/24 .........   site2:port2 IP:192.168.1.99/24 ,port3 Ip:10.10.10.51/24             ............Mt router 1 & Mt Router 2 Connected Port 3 By P2p link.

Comment: Click on the edit button on your initial question and format that stuff in a reasonable manner if you expect anyone to answer. You still haven't said what you tried and what doesn't work. For a simple diagram use something like Paint or something like [Draw.io](https://www.draw.io/).

Answer (score 1):

[image]
From my understanding the above picture should be a representation of your current networks etup. What you'd like to do is setup a static route across the P2P link between Router A and Router B so the both 192.168.* networks can communicate with each other. Your answers indicate that the connection is actually working but only on /24 subnets.

Your question doesn't have any real question in it and your answers to comments on your questions don't have any real questions either just vague statements what might be the problem. Please add that information to your original question or comment on this answer which the actual question you have.

Comment: Thanks sir ! for your given answer. i am new in mikrotik Router. your are given network map is same for my network.
i don't use any isp for static routing. p2p link is ok but i don't get ip address ping to both network 192.168.1.0/24,192.168.2.0/24.  
 how can i connect two different network in this  P2P Link?

please help me.

Comment: Why did you not supply it yourself? How did you check the ping?